# Copy Items in Lotus Script not working

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

There is a form containing rich text field and has text and doc link in it.
I want to send a mail on a scheduled agent with content from the rich text field into body of the mail.

I am facing issue that only the last line and doc link is getting into the body when I use below:

`Set item = doc.GetFirstItem( "Body" )
    Set memo = New NotesDocument( db )
    memo.Form = "Memo"
    memo.Subject = "Here's a copy of the review."
    Call memo.CopyItem( item, "Body" )`

Can any one please suggest something

Answer (score 0):

`NotesDocument.CopyMemo` should work properly, but if it does not, this code should solve your task:

```
Dim currentDoc as NotesDocument
Dim item as Variant
Dim memo as NotesDocument

'.....  initializing db, currentDoc & other code, etc ....

Set item = currentDoc.getFirstItem("Body")
Set memo = new NotesDocument(db)
memo.Form = "Memo"
memo.Subject = "Here's a copy of the review"

Call item.CopyItemToDocument(memo)
```

Comment: I think this will add the content of Memo into item but I need vice versa and what should be the second argument here? "doc"?

Comment: `item.CopyItemToDocument(memo)` copies item, which belongs to `currentDoc` to the `memo` document.

Comment: Call item.CopyItemToDocument(memo, "Body")

Comment: @CasperSkovgaard the second argument is not necessary unless the name of the new item is different.